# Calculate probability given dependent events

Tags: probability

I'm having some trouble finding out how to calculate the probability of the following problem:

[image]

I'm confused as to how I should be calculating the probability of B. I'm not sure how to factor in the possibility of A winning in one state but B winning in another.

Comment: What is the purpose of putting the problem as an image, when it seems easier to just type it in?  By putting the problem as an image, you are making it more difficult for search engines to access the text of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer your instructor or book is looking for is that there is a 50% chance that B wins Kentucky, and if he does not, then there is a 28% chance that he wins Tennessee.  The total probability that B wins at least one is then 50% plus (1 - 50%) times  28%, for a total of 64%.

There are some subtleties for the purist; for example, the conditions given are not unabiguously consistent.  But it is clear you are not meant to overthink the matter.

Comment: It's a bit quicker to calculate the probability that A wins in both states, then subtract from 1 to find the probability that B wins in at least one state.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the event that party A wins in Kentucky.  Let $T$ be the event that party A wins in Tennessee.  The events of B winning in each state is the complementary events $K^c, T^c$

We are given: $\mathsf P(K)=0.50,\, \mathsf P(T)=0.50,\, \mathsf P(T\mid K)=0.72$

We wish to find the probability that party B wins in at least one of the states.  This event is the complement of party A winning in both states.  We can then apply the product rule for the conjunction of conditionally dependent events.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(K^c\cup T^c) & = 1-\mathsf P(K\cap T) \\ & = 1 - \mathsf P(K)\cdot\mathsf P(T\mid K)\\ & = 1-0.5\cdot 0.72 \\ & = 0.64\end{align}$$